# iOS Xcode 4 UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

My program was working perfectly in iOS 4/Xcode 3. I recently upgraded to the newest version Xcode 4/iOS 5. I get a "SIGABRT" on the following line:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

This line is in the application did finish launching in the delegate. Here is some sample code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    rootViewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    rootViewController.window = window;
    window.rootViewController = rootViewController;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Impossible to diagnose this without more code. Something is probably going wrong when you initialize the rootViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" way to initialize `window` is like this:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
window.rootViewController = [Myclass alloc] init...
```

You're doing it other way round with

```
rootViewController.window = window;
```

and then

```
window.rootViewController = rootViewController; ???
```

Did that really work with the old xcode?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite strange how do use your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.

If you wanto to add a `UINavigationController` as a `rootViewController` for your `window` and then initialize that navigation controller with an instance of `MyCustomViewController` do the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    // code for creating a window
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    MyCustomViewController* myCustomViewController = [[[MyCustomViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myCustomViewController] autorelease];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

`window` within your application delegate `.h` is like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow* window; // using ARC
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow* window; // using not ARC
```

The property is also synthesised in your application delegate `.m` like

```
@synthesize window;
```

Some notes:

When you use `window.rootViewController` you don't need to call `[window addSubView:someview]`. It is already handled for you by iOS 4.

Are you sure that your code works in older sdks?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why are you doing `return YES` in `void` method?

Comment: @Eimantas I've fixed it, thanks. I've made a mistake beacause I was thinking it was written `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`. Cheers.